# Does selenium RC runs c# tests using java -jar option?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-rc

Is there any option available to run c#/.NET tests directly using selenium server like following option for html based tests?

( java -jar selenium-server.jar C# based tests/suites)

-htmlSuite    : Run a
   single HTML Selenese (Selenium Core) suite and then exit
   immediately, using the specified browser (e.g. "*firefox") on the
   specified URL (e.g. "http://www.google.com").  You need to specify
   the absolute path to the HTML test suite as well as the path to the
   HTML results file we'll generate.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To run your C# tests you will need to have the Selenium server running with

java -jar selenium-server.jar

and then you will need to compile the tests and use a .NET testing framework like NUnit, MBUnit or MSTest.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the C# tests aren't java, so I'd say no.  Guess you'd have to create a c# class, or something to run the c# API for selenium, or use nUnit.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question though?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium-RC acts as a web server. It accepts commands (in "selenese") in two fashions - via a HTML file, or via HTTP requests. (It can also accept them on the command line if you start it with the `-interactive` flag).

The various client languages are APIs that wrap the HTTP protocol. If you are using C#, then you need to write a C# program (possibly using NUnit, or some other .NET-baesd unit testing tool).

If you want a single-command option that will launch the Selenium-RC server and run your tests, you'll need to get your testing tool to execute the `java -jar selenium-server.jar` command on startup, and then send a shutdown command to it at the end.